# Firebase: Get notified just after the firebase-function trigger promise completed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my app I pushed some object to my firebase-database and immediately after that (after the then-promise fully filled) I fetch the object (with the returned key) from the database (with the on-value method).

In addition, I make some changes on the pushed object using the firebase-functions.

How can I receive the object (in the app) just after the changes and not before? (like other ordinary backend services)

Comment: So, listen to changes to the object immediately after it was added?   Maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If I understand you correctly. You want to add the object to the database, then the cloud function should make some changes to the object and update it. The problem you have is you get the object in your app both after its inserted and updated. You want only to get it after the cloud function has made some changes?

Comment: exactly, I don't want to get the object before the changes

Comment: The problem is that "doc.onSnapshot" gives you an event every time the document is updated. Instead I think you would have to create a normal API using cloud functions. You can create an HTTPS endpoint which creates your object and when it is completed it returns your object with a 201 HTTP code.

Comment: can you give me some example for that?

Comment: Yes sure thing, I'll provide an Javascript example as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you, I have not tested this piece of code but it should help you in the right direction.

Also dont use this exact code in production, there is plenty room for improvement, this is just an example code.

```
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req && req.body) {
      if (
        req.body.hasOwnProperty('name') &&
        req.body.hasOwnProperty('age')
      ) {
            const person = {
                name: req.body['name'],
                age: req.body['age']
            }

            // Make some changes to the person object
            person['hobby'] = 'Programmer';

            // Add object to FireStore
            admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('/persons')
            .add(person)
            .then((success) => {
                // Return the added & changed person
                res.status(201).send(JSON.stringify(person));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Error
                console.error('Something broke', error)
                res.status(500).send();
            });
      }
      else {
          // Error
          res.status(500).send({err: 'Missing property'});
      }
  }
  else {
      // Error
    res.status(500).send({err: 'Missing something'});
  }
});
```